# command python doesn't run script in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-catalina, pyenv

I wanted to have 2 versions of Python, thats why I installed `pyenv`
As a result if I've just run `python` in command line - it works:

```
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$
Python 3.7.0 (default, May  4 2022, 14:43:00)
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hello')
hello
```

If I run script in these  ways I see that works only old version of Python:

```
#Not works
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ python ~/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py  
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ python3 ~/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py 

# Works
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ python2 ~/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py  
  File "/Users/ilucy/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py", line 11
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /Users/ilucy/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py on line 11, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details


ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ cat ~/Dev/backend_test_homework/test_program.py
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dir_files = [filename.lower() for filename in os.listdir(BASE_DIR)]

files_list = ['program.py', 'readme.md']


def test_program():
    for filename in files_list:
        assert filename in dir_files, f'Файл `{filename}` не найден в корне репозитория'

    try:
        import program
    except Exception as e:
        assert False, (
            'Не удалось запустить `program.py`. '
            'Исправьте в нем ошибки:\n'
            f'{e}'
        )
```

What we have in configs

```
...
pyenv versions
  system
* 3.7.0 (set by /Users/ilucy/.pyenv/version)

...

cat ~/.bash_profile
export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH

...
cat ~/.bashrc
export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH

...

ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which python
/Users/ilucy/.pyenv/shims/python
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which python3
/Users/ilucy/.pyenv/shims/python3
...

ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which pyenv python
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
/Users/ilucy/.pyenv/shims/python

ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which pyenv python2
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
/usr/bin/python2

ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ which pyenv python3
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
/Users/ilucy/.pyenv/shims/python3

ilucy-osx2:/ ilucy$ env | grep "PATH"
PATH=/Users/ilucy/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

So it looks like Python3 doesn't works and smth is wrong in configs

Comment: Could it be that your script is working fine in `python` and `python3` via `pyenv` but doesn't have any output (it works silently) but FAILS when ran in a python2 environment throwing an error. That's what my assumption is looking through all of this. My guess is that `python` is rectifying to a `python 3.*` version via `pyenv` so likely `python` and `python3` are similar or the same python version.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html You appear to be using something other than UTF-8 to encode your source file.

Comment: If I run correct script it executes by all python versions

```python test.py
Hello World and Python3!

ilucy-osx2:Dev ilucy$ python3 test.py
Hello World and Python3!

ilucy-osx2:Dev ilucy$ python2 test.py
Hello World and Python3!

ilucy-osx2:Dev ilucy$ cat test.py
print('Hello World and Python3!')```

Comment: Read the commenting rules in stackoverflow